# Using PyPDF2 in a with Loop - Getting ValueError

Tags: python

I've got some code that loops over a list of pdfs, reads in each pdf in a PdfReader object and appends all but the last page to a single PdfWriter object.

Here is my code:

```
def remove_last_page():
    
    
    sorted_filenames = sorted(glob.glob('Reading*.pdf'), key = sort_key)
    writer = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()
    for file_path in sorted_filenames:
        with open(file_path,'rb') as file:
            reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file)
            
            for i in range(len(reader.pages) -1):
                writer.add_page(reader.pages[i])

    
    new_filename = 'Combined_Readings.pdf'
    
    with open(new_filename,'wb') as new_file:
        writer.write(new_file)
```

This gives me this error however:

[image]

which suggests that PyPDF2 is not interacting with the with block correctly.

I'm confident the pdfs are all fine.

Could someone point towards my error?

Comment: Did you try to manually open and close files?

Comment: Please post the error as a text, and not a screenshot.